What is this Tensor operation?
I am trying to identify an operation that takes two matrices of dimensions $n^2$ and output a matrix of dimensions $n^2$.
Every element in the output matrix incorporates all elements from the input matrices.
All possible multiplication pairs from elements of the input matrices appear only once throughout the output matrix. So individual output elements have all distinct pairs.
Here is an example given the matrices:
$$ A = \left[\begin{array}{cc} 
a_{11} &a_{12} \\ 
a_{21} &a_{22} 
\end{array}\right] \;\; , \;\; 
B = \left[\begin{array}{cc} 
b_{11} &b_{12} \\ 
b_{21} &b_{22} 
\end{array}\right]$$
What is the operation that produce:
$$operation(A,B) = \left[\begin{array} \\ 
a_{11}b_{11}+a_{12}b_{21}+a_{22}b_{12}+a_{21}b_{22} & a_{11}b_{12}+a_{12}b_{22}+a_{22}b_{11}+a_{21}b_{21} \\
a_{21}b_{11}+a_{22}b_{21}+a_{12}b_{12}+a_{11}b_{22} & a_{21}b_{12}+a_{22}b_{22}+a_{12}b_{11}+a_{11}b_{21}
\end{array}\right]$$
I find out that it is equivalent to these matrix multiplications;
$$operation(A,B) = AB + C_{up} A C_{up} C_{left} B$$
Where $C_{up}$ is a up Cyclic permutation and $C_{left}$ a left one.
The second term is basically the following matrix multiplication:
$$\left[\begin{matrix}
a_{21} & a_{22} \\
a_{11} & a_{12}
\end{matrix}\right]\left[\begin{matrix}
b_{22} & b_{21} \\
b_{12} & b_{11}
\end{matrix}\right]$$
If the matrices are 3x3 instead of 2x2, the result become:
$$operation(A,B) = AB + C_{up}A C_{up} C_{left} B + C_{down} A C_{down} C_{right} B$$
Does it relate to a standard tensor operation?

What is a standard tensor operation that you are expecting? You should consider representing $C_{up}$ and so on by matrices, then the operation is just a operation on the matrix ring.

Using the Einstein Summation convention this can be condensed to
$$\large{
\def\P{{\large\cal P}}
C_{kl} ;=; A_{ij} \  \P_{ijklmn} \  B_{mn}
}$$
where $\P$ is a sixth order permutation tensor whose components are either zero or one.

Thank you @greg, that was the answer I was looking for.
